# XML Schema issue, cannot find declaration of element

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a problem with a xsd which was given to me by a third party for their api.   The message i get is: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Message'

Here is the first few lines of my request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Message xmlns="http://www.surescripts.com/messaging" version="010" release="006" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:schemaLocation="http://aabrahams.staging.skycareehr.com/surescripts.xsd">
        <Header>
            --- more ---
```

And here is the beginning of the xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns="http://www.surescripts.com/messaging" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.surescripts.com/messaging" elementFormDefault="qualified">
        <xs:element name="Message" type="MessageType"/>
            <xs:complexType name="MessageType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Header" type="HeaderType"/>
                        <xs:element name="Body" type="BodyType"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    --- More ---
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did my answer help to resolve your problem?

Comment: I believe it would have, however as it turns out the third party that i'm working with actually misinformed me about having to host our own version of their xsd, so the result is i don't even have to specify it in my request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** The [XSD given by the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute](http://aabrahams.staging.skycareehr.com/surescripts.xsd) is not well formed: On line 1831 the close tag, `/xs:element>`, is missing a `<` character.  Fix it there, or copy it locally and fix.

**(2) In the XML file, change:**

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

to

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

**(3) Also in the XML file, change:**

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://aabrahams.staging.skycareehr.com/surescripts.xsd"
```

to

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.surescripts.com/messaging surescripts.xsd"
```

(Or, if you were able to fix `http://aabrahams.staging.skycareehr.com/surescripts.xsd` directly you can make it this:)

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.surescripts.com/messaging http://aabrahams.staging.skycareehr.com/surescripts.xsd"
```

*[That should do it, but if you have any more trouble, comment below and we'll address.]*